# Playing an audio file, from a web page, on a smartphone

Tags: html, audio, web, smartphone

I'm creating an alternate page of a web site just for smartphones that needs to play an audio file. I can reformat for mp3, ogg, wav, whatever works. I've tried the HTML5 "audio" tag and tested on an iPhone, with no luck. Anyone have any ideas and/or a link to a page that works?  -Thanks

Comment: What formats have you tested on iPhone? Remember, an `<audio>` tag can have multiple `<source>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Each phone is going to be a bit different, in what it supports.  Many devices support Flash, but not iOS.  It all depends on which platforms you are targeting.

If the audio doesn't have to be playing with the page visible, you can try just linking to a playlist file (such as m3u or pls).  Any device I've tested with supports this method, except for Android.  For Android, just load Flash.

Comment: The page has to be visible and no Flash.

Comment: @JohnRoblin, Well... best of luck with that.  You should also add those details to your question.  I don't think the solution that you are seeking exists, until we have widespread adoption of HTML5 on mobile devices.